# only read the length of variable-length array without reading the elements in hdf5

Tags: c++, c, hdf5, variable-length-array

Is it possible to do this?

I have an array containing `Nvl` [HDF5-variable-length-arrays](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html#Intro-PMCreateVariableLength) already written to a hdf5 file. I can read in the entire data by (*the following snippet is in c++, but answers using the C version of hdf5 API are equally welcome*)

```
hvl_t vl[Nvl];
dset.read(vl, VarLenType(&PredType:NATIVE_INT));
```

However, if I only want to read the length of each variable-length object, i.e., `vl[i].len` (for `i=0` to `Nvl-1`), how can I do it without reading in the data `vl[].p` as well?

Comment: Yes, using both C and C++ tags is appropriate because the HDF5 C++ wrapper follows the reference C API very closely.

Comment: @Simon: That is not a good enough reason. Tag the language you're actually using. Not some other language, some other language that looks a bit the same, or some other language a library was written in. The language you're _actually using_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done even though there is no direct function call to get it. You have to resort to the equivalent of the classical array size macro in C: `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`.

If your variable length array has type `vl_type`, then you can get its size in bytes with `vl_size = H5Dvlen_get_buf_size(vl_type)`. You then need to divide this size by the size in bytes of the type of the elements. This type can be found with `elem_type = H5Tget_super(vl_type)` and its size in bytes with `elem_size = H5Tget_size(elem_type)`.

Finally you have the length of the variable length array: `vl_size / elem_size`.

PS: I have used the C API here because the documentation is better but it works the same in C++.

Comment: That is _not_ the recommended way to get an array's size in C++. It's error prone and dangerous. See why accurate language tags matter? That being said ... I'm not even sure how else you'd do it with VLAs. Mainly because VLAs don't exist in C++. See why accurate language tags matter?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then feel free to remove the C++ tag as well because the language is irrelevant to the question :D

Comment: @Si​​​​​​​​​​​​mon: Were that true, the question would be off-topic.

Comment: @Simon: Thank you! But `H5Dvlen_get_buf_size` appears to be returning the total size of the buffer. What I want is the size of each element (i.e., `vl[i].len, for i=0 to Nvl-1`). Maybe possible with `H5Diterate`?

Comment: Looping through the elements (with hyperslab selection) and then query the size of each selection does the job! Not sure if this is efficient though. I've posted a snippet in a separate answer because I cannot format the code block in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Following Simon's answer, looping through the elements using `hyperslab` and then query the size of each element does the job.

```
hsize_t dim[1];
VarLenType vl_t(PredType:NATIVE_INT);
DataSpace dspace=dset.getSpace();
dspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dim);
hsize_t count[]={1}, offset[]={0}, stride[]={1}, block[]={1};
for(offset[0]=0;offset[0]<dim[0];offset[0]++)
{
      dspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, count, offset, stride, block); 
      cout<<dset.getVlenBufSize(vl_t, dspace)/vl_t.getSuper().getSize()<<" ";
}
```